# How to open the next HTML page after Login in the same browser that the user is currently using?

Tags: java, html

Currently I am using the following code:

```
String url = "http://www.google.com";       
java.awt.Desktop.getDesktop().browse(java.net.URI.create(url));
```

But this opens the specified url in my default browser. I want the application to open the next HTML page in the same browser.

Comment: what do u mean by next HTML?

Comment: Next HTML means say if the user is authorized then direct the user to MAIN.html and if he is unauthorized then to the same LOGIN.html page.

Comment: Isn't authorization and redirection something which the web application should do?

Comment: Actually I have java program which 
marshalls the credentials in xml->sends it to the server->unmarshalls the xml reply obtained from server and then accordingly redirects the user to Main.html or Login.html page.

Comment: You cant handle that redirect from your code. you have to use google api using oauth to get logged in user information. use this api to get logged in user information https://developers.google.com/+/web/people/ then give diffent url based on user information

Comment: Sorry Jagadeesh...bt i dont seem to follow you. :(

Comment: So the flow is
1. User Enter Credentials in Login.html
2. Login.html passes those credentials to Login.jsp
3. Login.jsp calls Login.java method
4. Login.java does the marshalling and unmarshalling and depending on the reply from server redirects the user to Main.html or Login.html